# PeeWee TimestampField retrieved as DateTime

Tags: python, datetime, unix-timestamp, peewee

Question regarding the use of TimestampField in PeeWee using Python 3.6. My model contains the following attribute:

```
timestamp= peewee.TimestampField(utc=True)
```

I store a timestamp as follows:

```
obj = TestObject(timestamp = Decimal(UnixtimestampString))
obj.save()

print(type(TestObject.get().timestamp))
```

Output:

```
Type: <class 'datetime.datetime'>
```

Is this normal behavior? I would like to retrieve the timestamp as Decimal (the way I put it in). Obviously I can convert it, but I was wondering why one would use TimestampField instead of DateTimeField when both return a DateTime object.

Is the only difference, the way the data is entered? (As a DateTime object in case of DateTimeField vs unix timestamp in Integer/Decimal for the TimestampField.)

Answer (score 2):

The `TimestampField` exists to store datetimes, expressed as timestamps, as an integer...but the Python representation is a `datetime` object.

If you want to work with integer (or float) timestamps, then there's no reason to use `TimestampField`, just use an `IntegerField` or `FloatField`.

Comment: Does `IntegerField` work beyond Y2k38? The peewee docs aren't clear as to whether this is backed with an int32 or int64...